# 'CategoryDetailView' object has no attribute 'get_object'

Tags: django, crm

I am setting up my CategoryDetailView for my CRM. Then this error occurred:

'CategoryDetailView' object has no attribute 'get_object'

here's my code sectrion from views.py:

```
class CategoryDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = "clients/category/category_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "category"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    clients = self.get_object().client_set.all()
    context.update({
        "clients": clients
    })
    return context
```

Here's my models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):

first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)

organization = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
agent = models.ForeignKey("Agent", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
category = models.ForeignKey("Category", related_name="clients", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)



class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30) # New, Tapped, Active, Closed
    organization = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with a [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview), not a [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview), and a `ListView` indeed has no [**`.get_object(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object). You furthermore should specify a `model = …` or `queryset = …` to specify with what queryset the `DetailView` is dealing.

You thus should inherit from the `DetailView`. You can also work with `self.object` to prevent making an extra query:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class CategoryDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'clients/category/category_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'category'
    model = Category

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        clients = self.object.client_set.all()
        context['clients'] = clients
        return context
```

There is als no reason to add this to the context, in the template, you can simply work with:

```
{% for client in category.client_set.all %}
    {{ client }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: plus OP doesn't specify the model / queryset in the view. Also they have set `related_name="clients"`.